# Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform returning rotated image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to use the Discrete Fourier Transform algorithm to transform an image, multiply it by a Gaussian filter, then apply the inverse to recover my modified image. In the textbook, it says that I can simply apply the same algorithm to recover my image. However, when I do so I am getting a rotated image (I think because of the sign of the exponential).

My code:

```
img1 = im2double(imread('Fig0431(d)(blown_ic_crop).tif'));
[M,N] = size(img1);

%pad and center the image
centered_img = pad_and_center(img1,M,N);
%compute DFT of image
trans_img = cust_fft(centered_img);

%Create Gaussian Filter
R=10; % filter size parameter 
X=0:size(trans_img,2)-1;
Y=0:size(trans_img,1)-1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(X,Y);
Cx=0.5*size(trans_img,2);
Cy=0.5*size(trans_img,1);
Lo=exp(-((X-Cx).^2+(Y-Cy).^2)./(2*R).^2);

%form the product G(u,v)
product_image = Lo .* trans_img;
%compute IDFT of product (take complex conjugate and multiply by 1/PQ
%first, per book section 4.11)
idft_img = (1/(2048*2048))*conj(cust_fft(product_image));
%get the real part to ignore computational inaccuracies
real_result = real(idft_img);
%center the real part of the inverse of the product image
centered_result = centered(real_result,size(real_result,1),size(real_result,2));%something wrong at this point
figure;
imshow(centered_result);
figure;
%compare to matlab's function
imshow(centered(real(ifft2(product_image)),2048,2048));
title('in built');
%extract MxN region at top of image to get final result
final_result = centered_result(1:M,1:N);
%figure;
%imshow(log(1+final_result));


%pad and center the passed image, passing dimensions of the image so that
%the image and filter will be padded to the same size
function f = pad_and_center(A,M,N)
%get padding paramters P and Q (must be power of 2)
p = nextpow2(M); q = nextpow2(N);
P = 2^p; Q = 2^q;
%pad the image
padded = padarray(A, [P,Q], 'post');
%center image
padded = centered(padded,P,Q);
f = padded;
end

%center an image
function f = centered(img, P, Q)
centered_intermediate = zeros(P,Q);
for i = 1 : P
    for j = 1 : Q
        centered_intermediate(i,j) = img(i,j) * (-1)^(i+j);        
    end
end
f = centered_intermediate;
end

%compute DFT of a padded and centered image using FFT algorithm from book
function f = cust_fft(img)
[P,Q] = size(img);%calling after centering image so sizes are still P and Q
transformed = zeros(P,Q);
wM = zeros(P,P);
wN = zeros(Q,Q);
for u = 0 : (P - 1)    
    for x = 0 : (P - 1)        
        wM(u+1, x+1) = exp(-2 * pi * 1i / P * x * u);    
    end    
end 
for v = 0 : (Q - 1)    
    for y = 0 : (Q - 1)        
        wN(y+1, v+1) = exp(-2 * pi * 1i / Q * y * v);    
    end    
end 
transformed = wM * img * wN;
f = transformed;
end
```

Prior to cropping the image, my code returns the following image:
[image]

but Matlab's code returns:

[image]

The section in the textbook I am basing this off of is the following from Woods:

```
Therefore,
Eq. (4-158) indicates that if we substitute F*(u,v) into an algorithm designed to
compute the 2-D forward Fourier transform, the result will be MNf *(x, y). Taking
the complex conjugate and dividing this result by MN yields f (x, y), which is the
inverse of F(u,v).
```

Am I just misunderstanding this, or is there some reason I can't simply apply the same algorithm to get the inverse? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I know if I added a sign term to the function cust_fft to handle the sign of the exponential when I'm finding the inverse I can get the properly rotated image, but I'm just wondering why the heck my code can't simply be reused for the forward and inverse transform like the text says. What have I missed?

Comment: I agree. the reason for rotation is the negative sign. the negative sign means a 180-degree rotation, which can be seen in your image. "Rotation in the spatial domain does the same in the Fourier domain".
take a look at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60012/what-effect-does-rotation-in-the-spatial-domain-has-on-phase-in-fourier-transfor